# How can I properly import a html notebook into R?

Tags: html, r, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

I have lecture notes in a html-format. I am new to markdown but I think it should be possible to open the lecture notes in RStudio. How would I dot that, given it is actually an html notebook.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s indeed an R HTML Notebook, there’ll be a popup menu with a link for the download of the source code at the top:

[image]

Use that link to download the Rmd source code for the notebook.